# Objects showing without LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I've got some source code example from the Microsoft ASP.NET website.

But the objects doesn't show the LINQ extensions.

Added the reference System.Data.Linq to the project and the class and still with no success.

Comment: Post a code segment, one you are trying to adapt to Linq.

Comment: Please don't include the URL here. What if that website goes down? This question goes for a toss then.

Comment: @InfoStatus: Why not? Works fine here. Add a using of System.Linq, rather than System.Data.Linq.

Comment: Yes, that was what was missing, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you add

```
using System.Linq
```

to your file? Since you are looking for the extension methods you need to include the namespace for the extensions to get 'active'.

And are the types you are trying to query enumerable?